# Updating collection view controller from cell value

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewController that I want to take orders for products.  Each custom collectionViewCell has a UIStepper to take the quantity for each product the user wishes to order.  Every time the value of the stepper changes, the price of the product is multiplied by the quantity and the total for that product calculated.

How would I go about passing this information back to the UICollectionViewController from each individual cell to calculate the overall total?

I was originally updating the controllers `total` property from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but realised that obviously doesn't update every time a stepper's value is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a protocol in your custom cell, and assign your view controller as a delegate. Every time the value changes in the cell it will send a message to the view controller, and then view controller can update its total accordingly.

Comment: Thank almas, using a protocol completely slipped my mind

Comment: Don't forget to click "accept" if my answer was helpful.

Comment: Done, wouldn't let me do it last night